# loop and char &

Tags: tables, macros

I can't find the problem in this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\mt
\newcount\mtt
\newcommand{\mttab}[2]{%
    \mt=0
    \loop
        \advance\mt by 1
        \mtt=1
        {\loop
           \advance\mtt by 1
           &
          \ifnum\mtt<#2
    \repeat}
    \\
    \ifnum\mt<#1
    \repeat
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
col1 & col2 & col3  \\
\hline
\mttab{15}{3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

the aim of this question is the simplest way to create an empty tabular

Comment: & begins/ends a group, and you can't straddle conditionals across it. You'll have to accumulate the row construction in a macro and then execute it.

Comment: It has been asked several times, I believe. Look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bloop+%2Btabular and choose your duplicate.

Comment: It is too bad this question has been closed. The OP's code had some problems which could be explained and fixed.

Comment: @Werner there are alternatives. And if this question had not been closed a better answer could be provided.

Comment: @egreg The vastitude of answers your search provides is an obstacle. I think when a question comes many times it deserves many answers. For example: why do we live and die?

Comment: @jfbu You can also drop one answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227084/appending-active-and-expansion-sensitive-characters-to-a-macro

Comment: @percusse No. This is not (necessarily, that's one of my point) the same issue. Besides adding answers to questions has a tendency to stimulate votes for the already accepted answer, the new one is read by a minority of site-seers. The question asked here has specifics (for example there is an error in `#1<->#2`) which need specific answer.

Comment: @percusse I had not seen you were the OP of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227084/appending-active-and-expansion-sensitive-characters-to-a-macro else I would have said "No, thanks for pointing that out" `:-)`

Comment: @jfbu See the end part of my reply to David under the question ;)

Comment: I find i simple solution and iedd it in the question. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: @touhami: I was voting to keep the question closed, but as you wrote a solution it is probably worth to reopen the question to let you post your answer in proper place.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Ok thank you. I think the question should be how to simply create an empty tabular?

Answer (score 11):

Before answering *How*, which does not have a unique answer ([your solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232628/4686) is a fine working answer), I will try to document *Why* your initial attempt failed. This knowledge could be handy to analyse more complicated situations.

First of all I recall that the crucial point is that you are trying to expand some macro from inside the tabular.

1. tabular cells create groups, hence all assignments should be made global. I would thus recommend here to use LaTeX counters as in LaTeX they are always managed globally.
2. it is not possible from inside a tabular cell to use a pre-defined TeX delimited macro (having a definition such as `\def\foo #1\repeat{stuff with #1}`) if `#1` will get a visible `&`: `\foo A & B\repeat C`, **except** if `\foo` is the very first thing in the cell (meaning that nothing non-expandable like a `\relax` or a `\def` or a `\setcounter` appeared before).

Fixes:

1. if you need to make definitions or assignments which will influence further cells, you must make them global,
2. if you need to fetch the `&` as a part of a delimited macro it must be somehow hidden, typically inside a braced group, or written as `\TAB` with a prior `\def\TAB{&}` or in something like `\firstofone{&}`  (`\def\firstofone #1{#1}`).

If we were to fix your original code according to these requirements, would it solve the problem?

Not yet, because the LaTeX loop construct does a *local* `\def`:

```
$ latexdef loop

\loop:
\long macro:#1\repeat ->\def \iterate {#1\relax \expandafter \iterate \fi }\iterate \let \iterate \relax
```

Your [own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232628/4686) gives a correct way out of this : you use all of your things in a single cell, the preparation of the macro with the tokens to be inserted being done entirely via `\g@addto@macro`. This solves efficiently your problem, and you can use `\count`'s rather than counters. What about point 2. above? well the `&` is appropriately hidden in the `\emttok{&}` (this was not necessary for the external loop, but the inner `\loop` without it would have seen the naked `&`).

Let me briefly discuss another way, which does not proceed by construction of a `\mttok`, and tries to work row after row, cell after cell. The most elegant is some expandable loop, but let's stick first with LaTeX's `\loop` and see what can be done.

First we need to let it to a global definition of `\iterate`. But immediately we hit against the problem of nesting. With this approach, the only way is to define two distinct loop macros, for example `\gloop` and `\ggloop`. Before doing so, there is more problem to mention.

There is an issue with the `\relax` after the `#1` in the definition of
`\iterate`. For example this will do `\ifnum 1=1\relax\expandafter\iterate\fi`. But this is catastropic because the `\relax` will 
properly terminate the test but it will stay in the token stream, and after a
`\\` this forces the start of a new row. Thus there will be a problem with an empty partial row, at the bottom of the tabular. We must get rid of the `\relax`. We could replace it by a space to be certain to terminate an `\ifnum` test, or we make sure we always use `\ifnum` with self-terminating numbers, moving the constraint on the caller side. Doing all this we end up with this approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\TAB{&}

% alternative to LaTeX's loop, for use in contexts were definitions
% must be made global to survive

% Thus we do global things, and we use distinct terminators to allow nesting.
% Careful that tests at the end of #1 must be self-terminating

\long\def\gloop #1\grepeat 
    {\gdef \giterate {#1\expandafter \giterate \grepeat }\giterate  }

\long\def\ggloop #1\ggrepeat 
    {\gdef \ggiterate {#1\expandafter \ggiterate \ggrepeat }\ggiterate  }

\let\grepeat\fi
\let\ggrepeat\fi

\newcounter{mt}
\newcounter{mtt}

\newcommand{\mttab}[2]{%
    \setcounter{mt}{0}%
    \gloop
      \stepcounter{mt}% careful with spaces from line endings
      \setcounter{mtt}{1}%
      (\themt)     % to see what happens
        \ggloop 
           \themtt % again to see where we are
           \stepcounter{mtt}%
           \TAB
        \ifnum #1>\value{mtt}%
        \ggrepeat 
      \themtt
      \\
    \ifnum #2>\value{mt}%
    \grepeat
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
col1 & col2 & col3\\
\hline
\mttab{3}{15}
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This produces (I know you asked for empty cells, but I added contents to visualize things):

[image]

The yet more elegant way is proceed with an expandable loop. LaTeX has one: `\@whilesw`. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142562/4686) explained how to use it. Here it would give the following approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mt}
\newcounter{mtt}

% recycling the \@whilesw of LaTeX into a num test
% \ifnum tests must be properly self-terminating
% I define the \xwhilenum slightly differently from my earlier use of it
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142562/4686

\makeatletter
  \newcommand*{\xwhilenum}[1]{\@whilesw{\ifnum #1}\fi }
\makeatother

% for reference, the LaTeX kernel definitions:
%\@whilesw:
%\long macro:#1\fi #2->#1#2\@iwhilesw {#1#2}\fi \fi 
%\@iwhilesw:
%\long macro:#1\fi ->#1\expandafter \@iwhilesw \else \@gobbletwo \fi {#1}\fi

\newcommand{\mttab}[2]{%
    \setcounter{mt}{#2}%
    \xwhilenum{\value{mt}>0 }% space after 0 is important
    {% must use braces here
      \addtocounter{mt}{-1}%
      \setcounter{mtt}{#1}%
      (\themt)     % to see where we are
      \xwhilenum{\value{mtt}>1 }% careful, N cells = N-1 &
      {%
         \themtt % again to see where we are
         \addtocounter{mtt}{-1}%
          &
      }% end of inner \xwhilenum
      \themtt
      \\
    }% end of external \xwhilenum
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
col1 & col2 & col3\\
\hline
\mttab{3}{15}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It gives (for a change I counted downwards):

[image]

A yet more elegant way perhaps is to dispense completely from using counters: one can do purely expandable loops thanks to `\numexpr`. But my answer is already a bit long, thus I will stop here.

Answer (score 6):

Producing rows of empty cells given the headers is quite easy with `expl3`: just nest two `\prg_replicate:nn` cycles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\emptytab}{mm}
 {% #1 is the comma separated list of headers, #2 the number of empty rows
  \touhami_emptytab:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_touhami_emptytab_cols_int
\clist_new:N \l_touhami_emptytab_headers_clist

\cs_new_protected:Npn \touhami_emptytab:nn #1 #2
 {
  % store the headers in a clist
  \clist_set:Nn \l_touhami_emptytab_headers_clist { #1 }
  % count the number of headers
  \int_set:Nn \l_touhami_emptytab_cols_int { \clist_count:n { #1 } }
  % make a tabular
  \begin{tabular}{|*{\l_touhami_emptytab_cols_int}{c|}}
  \hline
  \clist_use:Nn \l_touhami_emptytab_headers_clist { & } \\ \hline
  \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } % repeat #2 times
   {
    % produce <number of cols - 1> cell separators
    \prg_replicate:nn { \l_touhami_emptytab_cols_int - 1 } { & }
    \\ \hline
   }
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\emptytab{col1,col2,col3}{15}\qquad
\emptytab{col1,col2}{3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mttok}{}
\newcount\mt
\newcount\mtt
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\emttok}[1]{\g@addto@macro{\mttok}{#1}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\mttab}[2]{%
\renewcommand{\mttok}{}
    \mt=0
    \loop
        \advance\mt by 1
        \mtt=1
        {\loop
           \advance\mtt by 1
           \emttok{&}%
          \ifnum\mtt<#2
    \repeat}%
    \emttok{\\\hline}%
    \ifnum\mt<#1
    \repeat\mttok
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
col1 & col2 & col3  \\
\hline
\mttab{15}{3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to create an empty table with text only in the first line you needn't to use tabular environment (alias `\halign`) because the dimensions of the cells can be pre-calculated when processing the first line. My example shown below does measurement of the words in the first line and uses the most wide word as the `\tmpdim` width and `\tmpdim+1em` will be the width of all cells. The positive effect: all cells have the same width even thought the words have different width. And no tabular, no `\halign` but only `\hbox/\vbox` are used.

```
\newdimen\tmpdim
\newcount\tmpnum
\newbox\tabline

\def\struttab{\lower4pt\vbox to15pt{}}
\def\emptytab#1#2{\tmpdim=0pt \emptytabA#1,,\emptytabB\emptytabC#1,,\emptytabD{#2}}
\def\emptytabA#1,{\ifx,#1,\advance\tmpdim by1em \else
   \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
   \ifdim\tmpdim<\wd0 \tmpdim=\wd0 \fi
   \expandafter\emptytabA\fi
}
\def\emptytabB{\vbox\bgroup\hrule \setbox\tabline=\hbox{}\hbox\bgroup\struttab}
\def\emptytabC#1,{\ifx,#1,\vrule\egroup\hrule \else
   \vrule\hbox to\tmpdim{\hfil#1\hfil}%
   \global\setbox\tabline=\hbox{\unhbox\tabline \vrule\hbox to\tmpdim{}}%
   \expandafter\emptytabC\fi
}
\def\emptytabD#1{\tmpnum=0
   \loop
      \ifnum\tmpnum<#1
         \advance\tmpnum by1
         \hbox{\struttab\unhcopy\tabline\vrule}\hrule
         \repeat
   \egroup
}

\emptytab{first,second,third,four}{15}
```

A good rule: if you are creating a table with fixed width of cells then you needn't to use `tabular/\halign` tools becuase `\hbox to` is sufficient.

Comment: i will see this later today

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different approach.  I stick with your `\loop` approach, though I do rely on the `etex` macro `\unexpanded`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\mttab[2]{%%
  \ae@build@\ae@table@row{#2}{}{&}{\noexpand\\\noexpand\hline}%%
  \ae@build@\ae@table{#1}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\ae@table@row}}{}{}%%
  \ae@table
}

%% |------------------------------------------|
%% | "item" refers to either "column" or "row"|
%% |------------------------------------------|
%% | #1=commmand sequence to save row/table   |
%% | #2=number of interations to pass through |
%% | #3=content for each item                 |
%% | #4=inter-item content                    |
%% | #5=wrap up content                       |
%% |------------------------------------------|
\newcount\ae@build@cnt
\def\ae@build@#1#2#3#4#5{%%
  \let#1\relax
  \ae@build@cnt=0
  \loop
    \advance\ae@build@cnt by 1
    \ifx#1\relax
     \xdef#1{#3}%%
    \else
      \xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}#4#3}%%
    \fi
  \ifnum\ae@build@cnt<#2
  \repeat
  \xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}#5}%%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
col1 & col2 & col3  \\
\hline
\mttab{15}{3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

What's *nice* about this approach is the same macro handles both the create of the rows and the building of the remainder of the table:  no nested loops necessary, except *implicitly*.

Here's a rather different version here you pass the preamble for the `tabular` environment, the first row, and the number of rows.  You do not need to specify the number of columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

%% #1=preamble for tabular: should be simple "l", "r", or "c" separated only by "|" 
%% #2=formatting for the first row of the table                                     
%% #3=number of empty rows to generate                                              
\newcommand\mttab[3]{%%
  \ae@column@cnt=0 %%
  \ae@count@columns#1\relax%%
  \ae@build@\ae@table@row{\the\ae@column@cnt}{}{&}{\noexpand\\\noexpand\hline}%%
  \ae@build@\ae@table{#3}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\ae@table@row}}{}{}%%
  \ae@prepend@begin@table@\ae@table{#1}{#2}%%
  \ae@append@end@table\ae@table
  \ae@table
}

%% |-------------------------------------------|
%% | "item" refers to either "column" or "row" |
%% |-------------------------------------------|
%% | #1=commmand sequence to save row/table    |
%% | #2=number of interations to pass through  |
%% | #3=content for each item                  |
%% | #4=inter-item content                     |
%% | #5=wrap up content                        |
%% |-------------------------------------------|
\newcount\ae@build@cnt
\def\ae@build@#1#2#3#4#5{%%
  \let#1\relax
  \ae@build@cnt=0
  \loop
    \advance\ae@build@cnt by 1 %%
    \ifx#1\relax
     \xdef#1{#3}%%
    \else
      \xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}#4#3}%%
    \fi
  \ifnum\ae@build@cnt<#2
  \repeat
  \xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}#5}%%
}

\def\ae@prepend@begin@table@#1#2#3{%%
  \xdef#1{\noexpand\begin{tabular}{#2}%%
          \unexpanded{#3}%%
          \unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}}

\def\ae@append@end@table#1{%%
  \xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}\noexpand\end{tabular}}%%
  }

%% This macro moves through the preable for the tabular
%% and counts the number of tokens which are not "|".
\newcount\ae@column@cnt
\def\ae@count@columns#1{%%
  \def\ae@continue{}%%
  \ifx#1\relax
  \else
    \let\ae@continue\ae@count@columns
    \ifx#1|
    \else
      \advance\ae@column@cnt by 1 %%
    \fi
  \fi
  \ae@continue}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mttab{|c|c|c|}{\hline col1 & col2 & col3 \\\hline}{15}

\end{document}
```

The key to this succeeding is the macro which counts the number of columns.  It assumes that other than the column specifiers `l`, `r`, or `c`, only `|` occur in the `tabular` environment's preamble.

Answer (score 2):

Every time that one needs to automate a table, it is more flexible and opens more possibilities not to use a tabular, but to build the cells and rows from more elementary functions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\parindent0pt
\cs_set:Npn \make_table:nnn #1#2 #3 {
    \cs_set:Npn \cell_func:n ##1 {\framebox[2em][c]{\strut ##1 }~}
    \cs_set:Npn \head_func:n ##1 {\framebox[2em][c]{\strut c##1 }~}
    \int_step_function:nnnN {#1} {#2} {#3} {\head_func:n}\\
    \cs_set:Npn \make_rows:n ##1 { \int_step_function:nnnN {#1} {#2} {#3} { \cell_func:n}\\   }
    \int_step_function:nnnN {#1} {#2} {#3} {\make_rows:n}\\
}    
\make_table:nnn {1}{1}{10}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

LaTeX3 provides numerous looping structures buried in the `l3int` documentation.

[image]