# Foreach loop in tabular, missing endgroup inserted

Tags: tables, pgffor

I'm trying to create a table using the foreach loops made available in the `pgffor` package. Using the following code, I am able to generate the right contents, but not aligned properly.

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,7}{
        \foreach \j in {0,...,7}{
            (\i,\j)
        }
    }
\end{tabular}
```

However, as soon as I try to add line endings (see below), ..

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,7}{
        \foreach \j in {0,...,7}{
            (\i,\j) \\
        }
    }
\end{tabular}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.237         }
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone point it out to me?

Comment: cell in tabular is a group http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232472/loop-and-char

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302323/why-does-a-loop-fail-to-repeat-when-filling-longtable-contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the contents of the table to a macro *before* you typeset it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox}

\newcommand*\mytablecontents{}
\foreach \i in {0,...,7}{
  \foreach \j in {0,...,7}{
    \xappto\mytablecontents{(\i,\j) }
  }
  \gappto\mytablecontents{\\}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  \mytablecontents
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code above uses `etoolbox`'s `\appto<macro>{<stuff>}` which adds `<stuff>` to the macro `<macro>`. Or rather it uses its brothers `\gappto` which adds `<stuff>` globally (this is important because `\foreach` performs its loop inside a group) and `\xappto` which adds `<stuff>` globally and also expands `<stuff>` before its added to `<macro>`. The latter is important because otherwise `(\i,\j)` would be added multiple times but outside the loop `\i` and `\j` have another meaning – you'd get lots of “(ı,ȷ)”.

Comment: How can I arrange `\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
  \foreach \j in {1,...,6}
\foreach \k in {1,...,6}
   {
    \xappto\mytablecontents{(\i,\j,\) }

Comment: @toandhsp I don't understand your question. If you replace `{0,...,7}` with `{1,...,6}` both times you'll get (1,1) in the uper left corner and (6,6) in the lower right but I guess that's not the question, no?

Comment: @clements My question is
`\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
  \foreach \j in {1,...,6}
  \foreach \k in {1,...,6}
   {
    \xappto\mytablecontents{(\i,\j,\k) }
  }`

Comment: @toandhsp first you have to decide how you want to arrange the triplets and then you can ask a question of how to achieve the arrangement with LaTeX. Otherwise I'm not sure I can be of any help…