# putting figures in tabular with foreach (or an alternative)

Tags: tables, foreach

I have a number of figures coming from experiments; they are indexed with an integer number, and they are not always consecutive. Given a list of the indexes, I need to put them in a `tabular` of, say, 4 columns. After some searching I made this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline

\newcounter{imagecounter}

\foreach \n in {2,3,10,11,13,14,16,17,18,19,24,25,26,31,32,33,34,35,39,40}{
\stepcounter{imagecounter}
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{imagecounter}}{4}=0
& \includegraphics{image_index\n.png} \\
\fi
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{imagecounter}}{4}=1
\includegraphics{image_index\n.png} 
\fi
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{imagecounter}}{4}=2
& \includegraphics{image_index\n.png} 
\fi
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{imagecounter}}{4}=3
& \includegraphics{image_index\n.png} 
\fi
}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The problem is that, apparently, IF controllers must be inside `tabular` cells (is that the case?). I haven't been able to solve it or to find an alternative.

Is there a simple way to solve it? Is there another approach?

If so, please provide an example, I am very new to macros, new commands, and anything that is not straightforwards formatting text and tables.

Comment: please include a compilable example; for example `\intcalcMod` is a macro we can guess but it is not part of standard latex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the more or less standard way if one really wants to use `\foreach` inside the tabular.

(edit extends the code to cover the case where the number of images is not a multiple of the number of columns)

I followed suit and used an  `\intcalcMod` macro but it is more economical not to use anything like this but rather reset to zero the image counter after each row. This alternative is added next.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand*{\intcalcMod}[2]{\numexpr #1+#2-((#1+(#2/2))/#2)*#2\relax}
\newcounter{imagecounter}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \def\TEMP {}%
      \foreach \n in 
        {2,3,10,11,13,14,16,17,18,19,24,25,26,31,32,33,34,35,39,40}%
      {\stepcounter{imagecounter}%
       \xdef\TEMP {\unexpanded\expandafter{\TEMP}\noexpand 
                   \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image.png}%
                   (\n)}% (put it in the filename for the final version)
       \ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{imagecounter}}{4}=0
          \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\TEMP\expandafter{\TEMP \\}%
       \else
          \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\TEMP\expandafter{\TEMP &}%
       \fi
       }%
    \TEMP
% added for the case the total number of images is not multiple of 4
    \ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{imagecounter}}{4}=0
     \else\expandafter\\
    \fi
%
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Better not to use any `\intcalcMod` whatever it is:

```
    \hline
    \def\TEMP {}%
      \foreach \n in 
        {2,3,10,11,13,14,16,17,18,19,24,25,26,31,32,33,34,35,39,40}%
      {\stepcounter{imagecounter}%
       \xdef\TEMP {\unexpanded\expandafter{\TEMP}\noexpand 
                   \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image.png}%
                   (\n)}% (put it in the filename for the final version)
       \ifnum\value{imagecounter}=4
          \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\TEMP\expandafter{\TEMP \\}%
          \setcounter{imagecounter}{0}%
       \else
          \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\TEMP\expandafter{\TEMP &}%
       \fi
       }%
    \TEMP
    \ifnum\value{imagecounter}=0
     \else\expandafter\\
    \fi
%
    \hline
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another one assuming that you can use TikZ anyway and again you have multiples of 4 ( because it gives an *indexerror* with the PGF array lookup which can be fixed by testing the actual number of images at the start).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\def\imarray{{2,3,10,11,13,14,16,17,18,19,24,25,26,31,32,33,34,35,39,40}}
\def\TEMP{}
\foreach\x in {1,...,5}{% Row num, just guessing. 
  \foreach\y[evaluate={\mynum= {\imarray[int((\x-1)*4+\y-1)]};}
    ] in {1,...,4}{%Col num 4 given
      \xdef\TEMP{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\TEMP}%
      \noexpand\node{\noexpand\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} (\mynum)};%
      \ifnum\y=4 \noexpand\\\else\noexpand\&\fi%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[ampersand replacement=\&] (m) {\TEMP};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And we tried to collect this topic under [Appending active and expansion sensitive characters to a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227084/appending-active-and-expansion-sensitive-characters-to-a-macro)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `expl3`, that allows several features:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\loopimages}{O{}m}
 {% #1 is a list of options, #2 is the list of numbers
  \leon_loopimages:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { leon/loopimages }
 {
  name .tl_set:N = \l_leon_loop_name_tl,
  columns .int_set:N = \l_leon_loop_columns_int,
  columns .initial:n = 4,
  padding .dim_set:N = \l_leon_loop_padding_dim,
  padding .initial:n = 1em,
  last .choice:,
  last/center .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_leon_loop_align_tl { \centering },
  last/flush  .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_leon_loop_align_tl { \raggedright },
  last .initial:n = flush,
  leading .dim_set:N = \l_leon_loop_leading_dim,
  leading .initial:n = 1ex,
 }

\dim_new:N \l_leon_loop_width_dim

\cs_new_protected:Npn \leon_loopimages:nn #1 #2
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { leon/loopimages } { #1 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_leon_loop_width_dim
   {
    (
     \columnwidth - 
     \l_leon_loop_padding_dim * (\l_leon_loop_columns_int - 1)
    ) / \l_leon_loop_columns_int
   }
  \par % be in vertical mode
  \dim_set_eq:NN \lineskip \l_leon_loop_leading_dim
  \tl_use:N \l_leon_loop_align_tl % alignment
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \includegraphics[width=\l_leon_loop_width_dim]{\l_leon_loop_name_tl ##1}
    \hspace{\l_leon_loop_padding_dim}
   }
  \par
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\loopimages[
  name=image_index,
]{2,3,10,11,13,14,16,17}

\caption{Some images}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\loopimages[
  name=image_index,
  columns=5,
  last=center,
]{2,3,10,11,13,14,16,17}

\caption{Some images}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\loopimages[
  name=image_index,
  columns=5,
  last=flush,
]{2,3,10,11,13,14,16,17}

\caption{Some images}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The allowed keys are:

- `name` for the common part in the file names (this should of course be always present)
- `columns` to tell how many columns we want (default 4)
- `last` with value either `center` or `flush` (default) for telling how the last row will be set
- `padding` to set the space between the columns (default 1em)
- `leading` to set the vertical space between rows (default 1ex)

The mandatory argument to `\loopimages` is the list of indices.

[image]

The code computes the image width: we divide the column width by the number of columns after having subtracted the padding between columns. An `\hspace` is inserted between two images.