# Building table dynamically with `\edef`, `\noexpand` or whatever

Tags: tables, recursion

Consider the following table:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
a & A\\
b & B\\
c & C\\
\end{tabular}
```

I would like to define commands `\addtableline{...}{...}` and `\printtable` in order to build this table dynamically, i.e. I want to be able to write

```
% no tabular environment here
...
\addtableline{a}{A} % remembers line
...
\addtableline{b}{B} % remembers line
...
\addtableline{c}{C} % remembers line
...
\printtable % now generates table and typesets it
```

I played around with `\edef` and `\noexpand`, trying to recursively generate a command `\tablecontent` storing the table content, but I failed miserably. I guess the problem lies in the fact that the `&` is interpreted too early, outside the table environment. What brings me to this assumption is the fact that I was able to solve the problem if the result should be not a table, but rather simple text.

How can I solve the problem?

My try (might be complete nonsense):

```
\def\generatetableline#1#2{#1 & #2\\}
\gdef\tablecontent{}
\def\addtableline#1#2{\xdef\tablecontent{\tablecontent\noexpand\generatetableline{#1}{#2}}}
\def\printtable{\begin{tabular}\tablecontent\end{tabular}}
```

Comment: I've asked this question to be a general answer to such questions http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227084/appending-active-and-expansion-sensitive-characters-to-a-macro

Comment: Off-topic: There are answers to some of your questions -- please consider to accept one of them, thereby showing you respect the works and efforts of users here in order to answer them!

Answer (score 7):

There isn't any special trick to this, putting this under your "whatever" category.

You can append content to macro without expansions issues using the kernel-provided `\g@addto@macro`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\tablecontent{}
\newcommand\addtableline[2]{\g@addto@macro\tablecontent{#1 & #2 \\}}
\newcommand\printtable{%
  \begin{tabular}{ll}\tablecontent\end{tabular}%
  \renewcommand{\tablecontent}{}}% Clear \tablecontent
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% no tabular environment here
\addtableline{a}{A} % remembers line
\addtableline{b}{B} % remembers line
\addtableline{c}{C} % remembers line

\printtable % now generates table and typesets it

\end{document}
```

Similar options are provided by [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).

Answer (score 5):

More dynamic! The row cells are separated by commas (or another character settable in the optional argument). The command `\printtable` has an optional argument to specify column configurations different from the default `ll`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtableline}{O{,}m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_johnb_addtable_row_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_johnb_addtable_body_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l_johnb_addtable_row_seq { & }
    \exp_not:N \\
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printtable}{O{ll}}
 {
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
  \tl_use:N \g_johnb_addtable_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
  \tl_gclear:N \g_johnb_addtable_body_tl
 }

\seq_new:N \g_johnb_addtable_row_seq
\tl_new:N \g_johnb_addtable_body_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addtableline{a,A} % remembers line
\addtableline{b,B} % remembers line
\addtableline{c,C} % remembers line

\printtable % now generates table and typesets it

\bigskip

\addtableline{a,A,.} % remembers line
\addtableline[|]{b|B|,} % remembers line
\addtableline{c,C,;} % remembers line

\printtable[llc]

\end{document}
```

[image]