# How to automatic increasing row-col in table?

Tags: tables, macros, tabularx

My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,outer=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\only}[6]{% 
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{#1}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}
{\linewidth}{ l | X | X | X | X |}
\cline{2-5}
&  #2 &  #3 &  #4 &  #5 \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$R_1$} &  &  &  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$R_2$} &  &  &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$R_3$} &  &  &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$R_4$} &  &  &    \\ \hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$R_5$} &  &  &    \\ \hline        
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\only{Reading\label{tab:read}}{Colors}{Value}{Tolerance}{Power}

Table \ref{tab:read} is very important.
\end{document}
```

And output is

[image].

I wrote the following macro I'm trying to do. I wrote the macros below that I was trying to do. The letters in the columns are centered and the cells must be evenly spaced.

```
\only[row][col]{Table Caption}{Row1}{Row2}{Rown}{Col1}{Col2}{Coln}
```

For Example

```
\only[2][2]{Reading\label{tab:read}}{Colors}{Value}{$R_1$}{$R_2$}
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367979/latex-foreach-in-tabular-environment

Comment: @Andrew, I am checking that codes.

Comment: If any of the provided answers fully answers your question, you should accept the most suited one. Else, please specify why your answer (in it's current form) is not answered.

Comment: @Skillmon, Do not misunderstand me. I have about 100 pages of documentation. I check the tables. Until now, I have not been able to just center the text on the cell.

Comment: @Özgür see my second edit for the centring of all those columns in the tables created with `\only`. In all the other tables you can use `c` for a centred table of natural width or, if you want to centre a `p` type column or an `X` type column, you can use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}X` (if the `array` package is loaded).

Comment: Question is now closed. The table is fully functioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version just using `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\only@columns{\newcount\only@columns}
\@ifdefinable\only@columns@save{\newcount\only@columns@save}
\@ifdefinable\only@rows{\newcount\only@rows}
\newcommand\only@rowdefinitions{}
\newcommand\only@columndefinitions{}
\newcommand\only@end@rowdefinition{}
\newcommand\only@columntypes{}
\newcommand\only@columntype{X} % the type of each column to be used
\newcommand\only[1]%>>>
  {%
    \begingroup
    \def\only@caption{#1}%
    \only@a
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@a[1][2]%>>>
  {%
    \def\only@columndefinitions{}%
    \def\only@rowdefinitions{}%
    \def\only@end@rowdefinition{&}%
    \only@rows#1
    \only@b
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@b[1][2]%>>>
  {%
    \only@columns#1
    \only@columns@save\only@columns
    \ifnum\only@rows>0
      \expandafter\only@grab@rowdefinitions
    \else
      \ifnum\only@columns>0
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\only@grab@columndefinitions
      \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
      \fi
    \fi
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@grab@rowdefinitions[1]%>>>
  {%
    \edef\only@rowdefinitions
      {\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@rowdefinitions#1\only@end@rowdefinition}}%
    \advance\only@rows-1
    \ifnum\only@rows>0
      \expandafter\only@grab@rowdefinitions
    \else
      \expandafter\only@grab@columndefinitions
    \fi
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@grab@columndefinitions[1]%>>>
  {%
    \edef\only@columndefinitions
      {\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@columndefinitions&#1}}%
    \edef\only@columntypes
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\only@columntypes}%
        \unexpanded\expandafter{\only@columntype}|%
      }%
    \advance\only@columns-1
    \ifnum\only@columns>0
      \edef\only@end@rowdefinition
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@end@rowdefinition&}}%
      \expandafter\only@grab@columndefinitions
    \else
      \edef\only@end@rowdefinition
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@end@rowdefinition\\\hline}}%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\only@shipout\expandafter
        {\only@columntypes}%
    \fi
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@shipout[1]%>>>
  {%
    \begin{table}%
      \centering
      \expandafter\caption\expandafter{\only@caption}%
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | #1 }%
        \cline{2-\numexpr\only@columns@save+1\relax}%
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \only@columndefinitions\\
        \hline
        \only@rowdefinitions
      \end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}%
    \endgroup
  }%<<<
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\only{Reading}[30][8]{A}{B}{C}{A}{B}{C}{A}{B}{C}{A}{B}{C}{A}{B}{C}{A}{B}{C}{A}{B}{C}{A}{B}{C}{A}{B}{C}{A}{B}{C}{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}
\end{document}
```

Example output using only 3 rows and 3 columns:

[image]

**EDIT:** Alternative input method, because nobody loves counting :) Just put a `\EndRows` after the row names and an `\EndColumns` after the column names.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}% to make \pdf@strcmp available for other engines

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\only@columns{\newcount\only@columns}
\newcommand\only@caption{}
\newcommand\only@rowdefinitions{}
\newcommand\only@columndefinitions{}
\newcommand\only@end@row{}
\newcommand\only@columntypes{}
\newcommand\only[1]%>>>
  {%
    \begingroup
    \def\only@caption{#1}%
    \expandafter\only@grab@rows\expandafter{\detokenize{\EndRows}}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@grab@rows[2]%>>>
  {%
    \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter\pdf@strcmp\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}=0
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \edef\only@rowdefinitions
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@rowdefinitions#2\only@end@row}}%
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\expandafter\only@grab@columns\expandafter{\detokenize{\EndColumns}}}
    {\only@grab@rows{#1}}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@grab@columns[2]%>>>
  {%
    \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter\pdf@strcmp\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}=0
      \edef\only@end@row{\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@end@row\\\hline}}%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \edef\only@columndefinitions
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@columndefinitions&#2}}%
      \edef\only@end@row{\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@end@row&}}%
      \edef\only@columntypes{\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@columntypes X |}}%
      \advance\only@columns1
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\expandafter\only@shipout\expandafter{\only@columntypes}}
    {\only@grab@columns{#1}}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@shipout[1]%>>>
  {%
    \begin{table}%
      \centering
      \expandafter\caption\expandafter{\only@caption}%
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | #1 }%
        \cline{2-\numexpr\only@columns+1\relax}%
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \only@columndefinitions\\
        \hline
        \only@rowdefinitions
      \end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}%
    \endgroup
  }%<<<
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\only{Caption}{A}{B}{C}\EndRows{a}{b}{c}\EndColumns
\only{Caption}
{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}{L}{M}{N}{O}{P}{Q}{R}{S}{T}{U}{V}{W}{X}{Y}{Z}
\EndRows
{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}{i}{j}{k}{l}{m}
\EndColumns
\end{document}
```

(Output looks the same)

**EDIT2:**

Centred cell contents in every column:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}% to make \pdf@strcmp available for other engines

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\@ifdefinable\only@columns{\newcount\only@columns}
\newcommand\only@caption{}
\newcommand\only@rowdefinitions{}
\newcommand\only@columndefinitions{}
\newcommand\only@end@row{}
\newcommand\only@columntypes{}
\newcommand\only[1]%>>>
  {%
    \begingroup
    \def\only@caption{#1}%
    \expandafter\only@grab@rows\expandafter{\detokenize{\EndRows}}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@grab@rows[2]%>>>
  {%
    \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter\pdf@strcmp\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}=0
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \edef\only@rowdefinitions
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@rowdefinitions#2\only@end@row}}%
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\expandafter\only@grab@columns\expandafter{\detokenize{\EndColumns}}}
    {\only@grab@rows{#1}}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@grab@columns[2]%>>>
  {%
    \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter\pdf@strcmp\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}=0
      \edef\only@end@row{\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@end@row\\\hline}}%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \edef\only@columndefinitions
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@columndefinitions&#2}}%
      \edef\only@end@row{\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@end@row&}}%
      \edef\only@columntypes{\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@columntypes C |}}%
      \advance\only@columns1
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\expandafter\only@shipout\expandafter{\only@columntypes}}
    {\only@grab@columns{#1}}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@shipout[1]%>>>
  {%
    \begin{table}%
      \centering
      \expandafter\caption\expandafter{\only@caption}%
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | c | #1 }%
        \cline{2-\numexpr\only@columns+1\relax}%
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \only@columndefinitions\\
        \hline
        \only@rowdefinitions
      \end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}%
    \endgroup
  }%<<<
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\only{Caption}{A}{B}{C}\EndRows{a}{b}{c}\EndColumns
\only{Caption}
{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}{L}{M}{N}{O}{P}{Q}{R}{S}{T}{U}{V}{W}{X}{Y}{Z}
\EndRows
{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}{i}{j}{k}{l}{m}
\EndColumns
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT3:** Now there is a starred and an unstarred version of the macro. The one with a star would put the first row-argument in the top row next to the column arguments. Also, if you specify an empty caption argument, no caption will be used (it will still be put inside of a float though).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}% to make \pdf@strcmp available for other engines

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\@ifdefinable\only@columns{\newcount\only@columns}
\newcommand\only@caption{}
\newcommand\only@rowdefinitions{}
\newcommand\only@columndefinitions{}
\newcommand\only@end@row{}
\newcommand\only@columntypes{}
\newcommand\only@upper@border{}
\newcommand\only@first@row@first@cell{}
\newcommand\only%>>>
  {%
    \begingroup
    \@ifstar{\only@starred}{\only@unstarred}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@starred%>>>
  {%
    \def\only@upper@border{\hline}%
    \only@grab@caption
      {%
        \expandafter\only@grab@row@starred\expandafter{\detokenize{\EndRows}}%
      }%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@unstarred%>>>
  {%
    \def\only@upper@border{\cline{2-\numexpr\only@columns+1\relax}}%
    \def\only@first@row@first@cell{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}}%
    \only@grab@caption
      {%
        \expandafter\only@grab@rows\expandafter{\detokenize{\EndRows}}%
      }%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@grab@caption[2]%>>>
  {%
    \def\only@caption{#2}%
    #1%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@grab@row@starred[2]%>>>
  {%
    \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter\pdf@strcmp\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}=0
      \def\only@first@row@first@cell{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}}%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \def\only@first@row@first@cell{#2}%
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\expandafter\only@grab@columns\expandafter{\detokenize{\EndColumns}}}
    {\only@grab@rows{#1}}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@grab@rows[2]%>>>
  {%
    \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter\pdf@strcmp\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}=0
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \edef\only@rowdefinitions
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@rowdefinitions#2\only@end@row}}%
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\expandafter\only@grab@columns\expandafter{\detokenize{\EndColumns}}}
    {\only@grab@rows{#1}}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@grab@columns[2]%>>>
  {%
    \expandafter\ifnum\expandafter\pdf@strcmp\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}=0
      \edef\only@end@row{\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@end@row\\\hline}}%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \edef\only@columndefinitions
        {\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@columndefinitions&#2}}%
      \edef\only@end@row{\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@end@row&}}%
      \edef\only@columntypes{\unexpanded\expandafter{\only@columntypes C |}}%
      \advance\only@columns1
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\expandafter\only@shipout\expandafter{\only@columntypes}}
    {\only@grab@columns{#1}}%
  }%<<<
\newcommand\only@shipout[1]%>>>
  {%
    \begin{table}%
      \centering
      \expandafter\if\expandafter
        \relax\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\only@caption}\relax
      \else
        \expandafter\caption\expandafter{\only@caption}%
      \fi
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | c | #1 }%
        \only@upper@border
        \only@first@row@first@cell
        \only@columndefinitions\\
        \hline
        \only@rowdefinitions
      \end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}%
    \endgroup
  }%<<<
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\only*{Caption}{A}{B}{C}\EndRows{a}{b}{c}\EndColumns
\only{}
{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}{L}{M}{N}{O}{P}{Q}{R}{S}{T}{U}{V}{W}{X}{Y}{Z}
\EndRows
{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}{i}{j}{k}{l}{m}
\EndColumns
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is good working.

Comment: @Özgür wait for an edit, the input obviously has drawbacks...

Comment: @Özgür imho, better syntax in the edit.

Comment: It is perfect working.

Comment: Now I do not know if it would be right to ask a question. But one last question; If some tables require it, how do I change the code to write to the upper left empty cell? So to shift the text in the left column up.

Comment: @Özgür you'd have to add the first row definition to `\only@columndefinitions` instead of `\only@rowdefinitions` and remove the `\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}` from `\only@shipout`. Additional you'd want to change the `\cline` to a `\hline`.

Comment: I don't do add the first row definition to \only@columndefinitions instead of \only@rowdefinitions. I just could not do that. I'm adding, but the result is not an answer. Where exactly is it?

Comment: @Özgür see my edit on a way how this could be done.

Comment: Spectacular, exceptional.

Comment: @Özgür please refrain from posting comments like this in the future. Sole "Thank you" or "Works great" comments are of almost no value for future visitors. I'm glad I could helped.

Answer (score 4):

I have defined a macro `\mytable` that takes five arguments, with the second and third arguments being optional. The arguments are:

- `#1` is the table caption
- `#2` generates a label for the table of the form `tab:#2`. By default, `#2` is `#1`.
- `#3`, which is delimited by brackets, is character in the first column. It defaults to `R`.
- `#4` is the number of non-header rows
- `#5` is a comma separated list of column headers

Using this macro, the lines

```
  \mytable{Reading}{3}{Colors,Value,Tolerance,Power}

  \bigskip

  \mytable{Writing}[write](S){2}{Colors,Value,Power}
```

produce

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_headers_seq
\int_new:N \g_table_int
\int_new:N \g_columns_int
% \mytable{caption}[label](R){#rows}{column headers}
\NewDocumentCommand\mytable{ m O{#1} D(){R} mm}{
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_headers_seq {#5}
  \int_set:Nn \g_columns_int {\seq_count:N \l_headers_seq }
  \begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{#1}\label{tab:#2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l *{\int_use:N \g_columns_int}{|X}|}
      \hline
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_headers_seq { &##1} \\\hline
      \int_zero:N \g_table_int
      \prg_replicate:nn {#4}
      {
         \int_gincr:N \g_table_int
         $#3\sb{\int_use:N \g_table_int}$
         \prg_replicate:nn {\int_use:N \g_columns_int} {&} \\\hline
      }
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \mytable{Reading}{3}{Colors,Value,Tolerance,Power}

  \bigskip

  \mytable{Writing}[write](S){2}{Colors,Value,Power}

\end{document}
```

The macro uses [expl3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) package.

**Edit**

In the comment the OP asks for variable row headers as well. The following modification of the code above achieves this.

The new `\mytable` macro now takes 4 arguments:

- `#1` is the table caption
- `#2` generates a label for the table of the form `tab:#2`. By default, `#2` is `#1`.
- `#3` is a comma separated list of column headers
- `#4` is a comma separated list of row headers

Now the input

```
  \mytable{Reading}{Colors,Value,Tolerance,Power}{Row 1, Row 2, Row 3}

  \bigskip

  \mytable{Writing}[write]
       {Colors,Value,Power}
       {$A_1$, $D_2$, $R_1$, $S_3$}

  See Table~\ref{tab:Reading} and Table~\ref{tab:write}
```

produces:

[image]

The modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_header_seq
\seq_new:N \l_row_seq
\int_new:N \l_columns_int
\tl_new:N \l_ampersands_tl
\tl_new:N \l_table_row_tl
% \mytable{caption}[label]{column headers}{row headers}
\NewDocumentCommand\mytable{ m O{#1} mm}{
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_header_seq {#3}
  \tl_clear:N \l_ampersands_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_header_seq 
      {\tl_put_right:Nn \l_ampersands_tl {&}}
  % now construct the table rows
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_row_seq {#4}
  \tl_clear:N \l_table_row_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_row_seq {
     \tl_put_right:Nn \l_table_row_tl 
         {##1 \tl_use:N \l_ampersands_tl \\ \hline}
  }

  \int_set:Nn \l_columns_int {\seq_count:N \l_header_seq }
  \begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{#1}\label{tab:#2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l *{\l_columns_int}{|X}|}
      \cline{2-\int_eval:n{ \l_columns_int+1} }
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\tl_use:N \l_ampersands_tl \\\hline
      \tl_use:N \l_table_row_tl
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn {Nx}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \mytable{Reading}{Colors,Value,Tolerance,Power}{Row 1, Row 2, Row 3}

  \bigskip

  \mytable{Writing}[write]
       {Colors,Value,Power}
       {$A_1$, $D_2$, $R_1$, $S_3$}

  See Table~\ref{tab:Reading} and Table~\ref{tab:write}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good working. But can `[R]` be replaced with variable letters? `A_1`, `D_2`, `R_1` like `Reading` `Measuring` ... How do I eliminate the borders of the upper left cell?

Comment: @Özgür See my edit -- almost...

Comment: So, I'm waiting your edit.

Comment: @Özgür Not sure what is causing the issue with the last row, Will look at this tomorrow.

Comment: No problem. I learned a bit from your codes. Have a good day.

Comment: @Andrew Look at the `\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_row_seq { ##1 \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_header_seq { & } \\\hline }`-loop. Putting something behind the `\\\hline` that catches 3 arguments and shows them and puts them back yields that there is a not-vanishing sequence `\__prg_break_point:Nn \seq_map_break: \__seq_pop_item_def:` behind the `\\\hline` belonging to the last row-item. This non-vanishing sequence which seems to serve for terminating the loop yields an additional unwanted table-row. I suggest using a loop that works fully expandable.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thanks very much for trouble shooting! Not sure which loops are expandable so I ended up constructing the table using token lists.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good. Just add `&` for the missing column and a few `%` here and there and define a columntype `Y` and everything turns out nicely. :-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,outer=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand{\only}[6]{% 
\begin{table}[h!]%
\caption{#1}%
\centering
\begin{tabularx}%
{\linewidth}{ l | Y | Y | Y | Y |}%
\cline{2-5}%
&  #2 &  #3 &  #4 &  #5 \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$R_1$} &  &  &  & \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$R_2$} &  &  &  & \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$R_3$} &  &  &  & \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$R_4$} &  &  &  & \\ \hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$R_5$} &  &  &  & \\ \hline        
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}%
}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\only{Reading\label{tab:read}}{Colors}{Value}{Tolerance}{Power}

Table \ref{tab:read} is very important.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Off the cuff I can offer some nested looping for automatizing the creation of the tables.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,%
            bottom=2.5cm,marginparwidth=0cm,%
            marginparsep=0cm,outer=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Paraphernalia:
%%.........................................................................
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@bracestripexchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
%%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@ActOnFirstListElement{<action>}%
%%                       {<action when no (more) arguments are in list>}%
%%                       {<preset>}%
%%                       {{<e_k>}{<e_(k+1)>}..{<e_n>}}%
%% yields either: <action when no (more) arguments are in list><preset>
%%            or: <action>{<e_k>}<preset>{{<e_(k+1)>}..{<e_n>}}
%%
%%   (   The "list" in question is {<e_k>}{<e_(k+1)>}..{<e_n>}   )
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@KeepFirstTillSelDOM{}%
\long\def\UD@KeepFirstTillSelDOM#1#2\UD@SelDOM{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ActOnFirstListElement[4]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@secondoftwo#4.{}}%
  {#2#3}%
  {%
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter            \UD@ExtractFirstListElementLoop
    \expandafter\UD@bracestripexchange
    \expandafter{%
    \expandafter{%
    \UD@firstoftwo{}#4}}{{#4\UD@SelDOM}{#1}{#3}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstListElementLoop[3]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {#2#1#3}%
  {%
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstListElementLoop
    \expandafter{%
    \UD@KeepFirstTillSelDOM#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% David Kastrup's \replicate:
%%.........................................................................
%% <http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls/2005p/david-kastrup/bachotex2005-david-kastrup-pearl3.pdf>
\newcommand\DK@recur[1]{\csname DK@rn#1\DK@recur}%
\newcommand\DK@rnm[1]{\endcsname{#1}#1}%
\newcommand\DK@rn[1]{}%
\newcommand\DK@replicate[1]{\csname DK@rn\expandafter\DK@recur
\romannumeral\number\number#1 000\endcsname\endcsname}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \CreateTable[<caption>]{<columns>}{<rows>}
%%     a caption will be placed only in case the optional
%%     <caption> is neither empty nor holding only a space token.
%%.............................................................................
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand*\CreateTable[3][]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@secondoftwo#2.{}}{%
    \@latex@error{No table-columns specified}{Specify at least one table-column.}%
  }{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@secondoftwo#3.{}}{%
      \@latex@error{No table-rows specified}{Specify at least one table-row.}%
    }{%
      \UD@ActOnFirstListElement{\@CreateTableHead}
                               {\@CreateTableRows{#3}{#1}}%
                               {%
                                  {1}{0}{}{l|}%
                                  {\@CreateTableHead}{\@CreateTableRows{#3}{#1}}%
                               }%
                               {#2}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\@CreateTableHead[7]{%
  \begingroup
  \@tempcnta=#2\relax
  \advance\@tempcnta by 1\relax
  \expandafter\UD@bracestripexchange
  \expandafter{\expandafter{\expandafter{\the\@tempcnta}%
  %{#2}{#4&#1}{#5X|}{#6}{#7}}}%
  {#2}{#4&#1}{#5Y|}{#6}{#7}}}%
  {\endgroup\UD@ActOnFirstListElement{#6}{#7}}%
}%
%
\newcommand\@CreateTableRows[8]{%
  \begin{table}[h!]%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@secondoftwo#2.{}}%
    {}{\caption{#2}}%
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{#6}%
  \cline{2-#3}%
  #5\\\hline
  \UD@ActOnFirstListElement{\@CreateTableRow}%
                           {\expandafter\@gobbletwo\@gobble}%
                           {{#4}{\@CreateTableRow}{\expandafter\@gobbletwo\@gobble}}%
                           {#1}%
  \end{tabularx}%
  \end{table}%
}%
\newcommand\@CreateTableRow[4]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{#1}\DK@replicate{#2}{&}\\\hline
  \UD@ActOnFirstListElement{#3}{#4}{{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\CreateTable[Reading\label{tab:read}]%
            {{Colors}{Value}{Tolerance}{Power}}%
            {{$R_1$}{$R_2$}{$R_3$}{$R_4$}{$R_5$}}%

\CreateTable[AnotherReading\label{tab:anotherread}]%
            {%
              {Col 1}{Col 2}{Col 3}{Col 4}{Col 5}{Col 6}%
              {Col 7}{Col 8}{Col 9}{Col 10}{Col 11}{Col 12}%
            }%
            {%
              {$R_1$}{$R_2$}{$R_3$}{$R_4$}{$R_5$}%
              {$R_6$}{$R_7$}{$R_8$}{$R_9$}{$R_{10}$}%
            }%

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

An approach using expl3-Syntax could be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,%
            bottom=2.5cm,marginparwidth=0cm,%
            marginparsep=0cm,outer=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_header_seq
\seq_new:N \l_row_seq
\int_new:N \l_columns_int
\cs_new:Npn \row_add_mc:n #1
{
  #1\seq_map_function:NN \l_header_seq \emptycell_add_mc:n\\\hline
}

\cs_new:Npn \emptycell_add_mc:n #1
{
  & 
}

\cs_new:Npn \headcell_add_mc:n #1
{
  & #1
}

% \mytable{caption}[label]{column headers}{row headers}
\NewDocumentCommand\CreateTable{ m O{#1} mm}{
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_header_seq {#3}
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_row_seq {#4}
  \int_set:Nn \l_columns_int {\seq_count:N \l_header_seq }
  \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{#1}\label{tab:#2}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l *{\l_columns_int}{|Y}|}%
      \cline{2-\int_eval:n{ \l_columns_int+1} }%
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\seq_map_function:NN \l_header_seq \headcell_add_mc:n\\\hline
      \seq_map_function:NN \l_row_seq \row_add_mc:n
    \end{tabularx}%
  \end{table}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\CreateTable{Reading}[read]{Colors,Value,Tolerance,Power}{$R_1$,$R_2$,$R_3$,$R_4$,$R_5$}

\bigskip

\CreateTable{Another Reading}[anotherread]
        {Col 1,Col 2,Col 3,Col 4,Col 5,Col 6, Col 7,Col 8,Col 9,Col 10,Col 11,Col 12 }
        {$R_1$, $R_2$, $R_3$, $R_4$, $R_5$, $R_6$, $R_7$, $R_8$, $R_9$, $R_{10}$}

See Table~\ref{tab:read} and Table~\ref{tab:anotherread}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is good working. Also I will consider your warnings.

Comment: It is important to me to get 'warnings' from knowledgeable and experienced people like you. Please warn me always. ;-) Have a good day.