# How do you define a row macro inside a table?

Tags: macros, tabularx

I am trying to make a macro for the rows in my table, just to make it look a bit more elegant. However, the document fails to compile when I use more than one row.

Here's the code I'm trying to duplicate:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ r X }
  \bfseries{Topic1:} & Item1, Item2, Item3 \\
  \bgseries{Topic2:} & Item1, Item2, Item3 \\
\end{tabularx}
```

And my attempt to create a macro:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ r X }
  \newcommand{\row}[2]{\bfseries{#1:} & #2 \\}
  \row{Topic1}{Item1, Item2, Item3}
  \row{Topic2}{Item1, Item2, Item3}
\end{tabularx}
```

And the compiler error I'm getting is "Undefined control sequence." Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Table cells create groups, so definitions made inside a tabular cell don't make it until the next one. Move the definition outside the table.

Comment: Wow that was embarrassingly easy, thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, everyone did that at least once :-) Also note that your usage of `\bfseries` is incorrect. `\bfseries` doesn't take an argument and changes the font until the current group ends, so you should use as `{\bfseries #1:}`. Alternatively, use `\textbf`, which _does_ take an argument: `\textbf{#1:}`. By the way, welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by moving the definition outside the table.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for your help.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367979/latex-foreach-in-tabular-environment