# Cleaner way of making rows in a table dynamically appear

Tags: tables, titles, xparse

So what I have works, but I am looking for a cleaner / better approach.

I have a titlepage which needs a `\maketitle` in the form of a `table` (Tabular actually). However, when options are missing they should just be removed from the table. Similarly if no options are given, no table should be printed.

For instance

```
\def\@author{Jane doe}
\def\@date{\today}
\def\@verifier{Joe Doe}
```

Should produce

[image]

While

```
\def\@author{Jane doe}
\def\@date{}
\def\@verifier{}
```

becomes

[image]

This is my current idea, presented in as minimal of an example as I could make

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
    \def\@author{}
    \def\@date{}
    \def\@verifier{}
    % Comment out the lines bellow to test
    \def\@author{Jane doe}
    \def\@date{\today}
    \def\@verifier{Joe Doe}

\newcommand{\maketitletable}{
%
\newcommand*{\authorname}{author}
\newcommand*{\datename}{date}
\newcommand*{\verifiername}{verifier}
%
\ifstrempty{\@author\@date\@verifier}{}{
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth} p{\dimexpr 0.6\textwidth - 4\tabcolsep}}\toprule
        \ifdefempty{\@author}{}{& \authorname{} & \@author \\}
        \ifdefempty{\@date}{}{& \datename{} & \@date \\}
        \ifdefempty{\@verifier}{}{& \verifiername{} & \@verifier \\}
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \maketitletable
\end{document}
```

Just for reference, In my real code I do something like the following (I have many more)

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
    % Provide keys.
    \keys_define:nn { babylonia }
      {
        author         .tl_set:N  = \@author,
        author         .initial:n = {},
        date           .tl_set:N  = \@date,
        date           .initial:n = {},
        verifier       .tl_set:N  = \@verifier,
      }
    % Provide key setting command.
    \NewDocumentCommand\OUSsetup{ m }{
      \keys_set:nn { babylonia } { #1 }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and then

```
\makeatletter 

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{% 
...
minimal working example goes in here
...
}

\makeatother
```

Before finally setting

```
\OUSsetup{
  author    = Jane Doe,
  date      = 01.12.2021,
  verifier  = Joe Doe,
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I am guessing this makes no difference to how the table is implemented.

Comment: So I guess you want some way to avoid the repetition? Be careful, sometimes the actual code is so complex it's unreadable (although with expl3 etc. it's less bad) -- can we assume \Xname always equal X?

Comment: Actually if you already use keyval it has the `.code:n` interface to simply specify the code to be executed. If the user specifies the keys in correct order (unlikely?) just use that to typeset the rows directly

Comment: Yes, we can always assume `\Xname` always equals `X` as these are defined by me. I just want to avoid some of the repetition =) And no, we can not rely on the users to input the keys in the correct order. Also a bit messy to avoid printing the `bottomrule` / `toprule` when no keys are present. Note that not every key in `\OUSsetup` will be in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\makeatletter

\def\@author{}
\def\@date{}
\def\@verifier{}

\def\authorname{author}
\def\datename{date}
\def\verifiername{verifier}

\newcommand*{\mycheckempty}[1]{\ifcsempty{@#1}{}{\csuse{#1name}\strut}}

\newcommand{\maketitletable}{%
\ifstrempty{\@author\@date\@verifier}{}{%
    \noindent
    \begin{booktabs}{
      colspec={X[2]X[2]X[6]},
      stretch=0, rowsep=0pt, column{2}={cmd=\mycheckempty},
    }
      \toprule
        & author   & \@author   \\
        & date     & \@date     \\
        & verifier & \@verifier \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{booktabs}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\def\@author{Jane doe}
\def\@date{\today}
\def\@verifier{Joe Doe}
\maketitletable
  
\bigskip

\def\@author{Jane doe}
\def\@date{}
\def\@verifier{}
\maketitletable

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution (least modification to the existing code) would be to simply define an auxiliary macro (because of [issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495714/how-do-you-define-a-row-macro-inside-a-table) the macro must be defined outside, and some [other issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367979/latex-foreach-in-tabular-environment) with TikZ `\foreach`)

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\def\@author{}
\def\@date{}
\def\@verifier{}
% Comment out the lines bellow to test
\def\@author{Jane doe}
\def\@date{\today}
\def\@verifier{Joe Doe}

\newcommand\printrow[1]{%  ← this is the auxiliary macro ========
    \ifcsempty{@#1}{}{  & \csuse{#1name} & \csuse{@#1} \\ }%
    %                     ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑    might be replaced with simply #1 if you're sure
}

\newcommand{\maketitletable}{
%
\newcommand*{\authorname}{author}
\newcommand*{\datename}{date}
\newcommand*{\verifiername}{verifier}
%
\ifstrempty{\@author\@date\@verifier}{}{
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth} p{\dimexpr 0.6\textwidth - 4\tabcolsep}}\toprule
        \printrow{author}  % ======== use it like this
        \printrow{date}
        \printrow{verifier}
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \maketitletable
\end{document}
```

Alternative solution with expl3.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\def\@author{}
\def\@date{}
\def\@verifier{}
% Comment out the lines bellow to test
\def\@author{Jane doe}
\def\@date{\today}
\def\@verifier{Joe Doe}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \tl_if_empty:n {x} {F}

\cs_set_protected:Npn \__process_item:n #1 {
    \tl_if_empty:cF {@#1} { & \use:c{#1name} & \use:c {@#1} \\ }
}

\newcommand{\maketitletable}{
%
\newcommand*{\authorname}{author}
\newcommand*{\datename}{date}
\newcommand*{\verifiername}{verifier}
%
\tl_if_empty:xF{\@author\@date\@verifier}{
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth} p{\dimexpr 0.6\textwidth - 4\tabcolsep}}\toprule
        \clist_map_function:nN {author, date, verifier} \__process_item:n
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \maketitletable
\end{document}
```

Note that using `\clist_map_inline` directly will not work (`Misplaced \noalign.`) because of some low level TeX reasons (roughly speaking, at high revel `\\ \bottomrule` does work, while `\\ \relax \bottomrule` doesn't, and `\clist_map_inline` does some unexpandable things between `\\` and `\bottomrule`)

Comment: Generally speaking I recommend learning expl3 over e.g. etoolbox or similar. In this case at least the command naming scheme are more consistent

Comment: I tried to define some commands using `&` but as you mentioned there are plenty issues with expandability. I see you recommend avoiding `etoolbox` (which I agree with), but why are we still using `\ifstrempty`? Could we have used `\tl_if_empty:cF`?

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that one.