# etoolbox do with macro as parameter

Tags: etoolbox

I'm trying to make an automatized meeting log generator using pdflatex. I want to create a table with the n rows, and fill them up with comma separated typein inputs. I've got the `myTable` macro from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367988/237426), and it works fine, if I directly write in the text. (1) But if I use the `\def\variable` or `\typein[\variable]{variable}` (2) it fails with the error shown below.

As I understand I probably should use `\expandafter` somewhere in some way, but I couldn't figured it out myself.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\variable{Person 1/Active/Online/X,Person 2/Active/-/-,Person 3/Intern/Office/X}

\def\addtablerow#1/#2/#3/#4!{\textbf{#1} & #2 & #3 & #4\\}
\newcommand{\myTable}[1]{
    \renewcommand*\do[1]{\addtablerow##1!}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth} | p{0.2\textwidth} |        p{0.2\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        Name & Role & Presence & Present \\ \hline
        \docsvlist{#1} \hline
    \end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}
    % 1
    \myTable{Person 1/Developer/Online/X,Person 2/Developer/-/-,Person 3/Intern/Office/X}
    % 2
    \myTable{\variable}
\end{document}
```

The full error:

```
\variable !\etb@lst@docsvlist \@nil \etb@lst@q@end ,& \hline \end {ta\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \addtablerow.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test.tex
            
! Emergency stop.
<*> test.tex
```

Answer (score 8):

The call `\myTable{\variable}` passes a list of length one. You need to access at the *value* of `\variable` before `\myTable` does its job.

So, as the other answer suggests is right, although there's no need to add an `\expandafter` in front of `\addtablerow`.

I suggest a different method, with `expl3` that avoids polluting the code with `\def`, using the analog of a namespace.

The `\printlist` macro takes a `*` if you want to use a list defined previously.

If all lists you need are like this, you can avoid the `*` variant, changing the code should be easy.

The working is much like that of `\docsvlist`, but with some advantages: spaces around the comma delimiters are ignored, for instance. Here `\clist_map_inline:nN` has a role similar to `\docsvlist` and instead of redefining `\do` you define a set of two macros, the first of which is the analog of `\addtablerow`, but has to be split into an external and an internal part.

The table preamble has been fixed to avoid overfull: your table is longer than the text width, because you aren't taking into account the intercolumn spaces.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definelist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { l_fauszt_list_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l_fauszt_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printlist}{sm}
 {% the star variant uses a list name
  % otherwise a full list is passed
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \fauszt_list_print:v { l_fauszt_list_#2_clist }
   }
   {
    \fauszt_list_print:n { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fauszt_list_print:n
 {
  \begin{tabular}{
    |p{\dimexpr0.4\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
    |p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
    |p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
    |p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|
  }
  \hline
  Name & Role & Presence & Present \\
  \hline
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__fauszst_list_print_row:n
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fauszt_list_print:n { v }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__fauszst_list_print_row:n
 {
  \__fauszt_list_print_row:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__fauszt_list_print_row:w #1 / #2 / #3 / #4 \q_stop
 {
  \textbf{#1} & #2 & #3 & #4 \\ \hline
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definelist{variable}{
  Person 1/Active/Online/X,
  Person 2/Active/-/-,
  Person 3/Intern/Office/X
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\printlist{Person 1/Developer/Online/X,Person 2/Developer/-/-,Person 3/Intern/Office/X}

\bigskip

\noindent
\printlist*{variable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Further generalizations are possible.

---

For completeness, I'll prove my statement that, in the solution proposed by [user237299](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587183/4427), the token `\expandafter` in `\expandafter\addtablerow##1` can be removed as it does nothing useful (and it can even do evil in corner cases).

Let's just follow the expansions. When `\variable` is defined as in the question and the call is

```
\noindent\expandafter\myTable\expandafter{\variable}
```

(first proposed solution), this is just the same as calling

```
\noindent\myTable{Person 1/Developer/Online/X,Person 2/Developer/-/-,Person 3/Intern/Office/X}
```

Then `\docsvlist` will determine the first item and pass it as a braced argument to `\do`, so the first cycle in the loop will perform

```
\do{Person 1/Developer/Online/X}
```

which would become

```
\expandafter\addtablerow Person 1/Developer/Online/X!
```

and the `\expandafter` is clearly useless.

In the second solution, the call is `\myTable{\variable}` and then the main bit is

```
\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\variable}
```

but it's just a variation on the first one and the working is exactly the same.

Then user237299 purports that the `\expandafter` I'm referring to will be useful in case the call is `\myTable{\variableTwo}`, where there has been

```
\def\variableTwo{\variable}
```

Unfortunately, this is not true. Indeed, using the first solution (but using the second would be exactly the same), one has

```
\expandafter\myTable\expandafter{\variableTwo}
```

that becomes

```
\myTable{\variable}
```

which calls `\docsvlist{\variable}`. The argument has no comma, so a single cycle is performed and the call becomes

```
\expandafter\addtablerow\variable
```

Nothing useful, because we'd get

```
\addtablerow Person 1/Developer/Online/X,Person 2/Developer/-/-,Person 3/Intern/Office/X!
```

Of course, doing `\def\variableTwo{\variable}` is quite meaningless in this context. If one wants to alias `\variable`, maybe for augmenting it while having the previous list still available, one should do `\let\variableTwo=\variable`.

Comment: This is very interesting, I'll give it a shot for sure. Thank you!

Comment: There in fact is an input in which that second `\expandafter` could make sense, which is when one stores a complete person inside a macro, something like `\printlist{\personA,\personB,\personC}` (but I'd use a `\tl_count:n` to only expand the first token when the input contains just a single token).

Answer (score 7):

You only need some `\expandafter`s.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\variable{Person 1/Active/Online/X,Person 2/Active/-/-,Person 3/Intern/Office/X}

\def\addtablerow#1/#2/#3/#4!{\textbf{#1} & #2 & #3 & #4\\}
\newcommand{\myTable}[1]{
    \renewcommand*\do[1]{\expandafter\addtablerow##1!}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth} | p{0.2\textwidth} |        p{0.2\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        Name & Role & Presence & Present \\ \hline
        \docsvlist{#1} \hline
    \end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}
    % 1
    \noindent\myTable{Person 1/Developer/Online/X,Person 2/Developer/-/-,Person 3/Intern/Office/X}
    % 2
    \par
    \noindent\expandafter\myTable\expandafter{\variable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\variable{Person 1/Active/Online/X,Person 2/Active/-/-,Person 3/Intern/Office/X}

\def\addtablerow#1/#2/#3/#4!{\textbf{#1} & #2 & #3 & #4\\}
\newcommand{\myTable}[1]{%
    \renewcommand*\do[1]{\expandafter\addtablerow##1!}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth} | p{0.2\textwidth} |        p{0.2\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        Name & Role & Presence & Present \\ \hline
        \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{#1} \hline
    \end{tabular}
}


\begin{document}
    % 1
    \noindent\myTable{Person 1/Developer/Online/X,Person 2/Developer/-/-,Person 3/Intern/Office/X}
    % 2
    \par
    \noindent\myTable{\variable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you guys! This is a tremendous help for me!