# What are the special meanings of # and ! for etoolbox?

Tags: characters

In this [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587179/etoolbox-do-with-macro-as-parameter), we find `##!` in the context of a `\newcommand` definition, and specifically right after the `\addtablerow` command from the etoolbox package is used. What does `##!` mean here? Why is it used?

Here is the code from that answer in which the `##!` appears after `\addtablerow`:

```
\newcommand{\myTable}[1]{
    \renewcommand*\do[1]{\addtablerow##1!}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth} | p{0.2\textwidth} |        p{0.2\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        Name & Role & Presence & Present \\ \hline
        \docsvlist{#1} \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
```

I don't see an explanation in the etoolbox or etex documentation, so I am not sure where this would be documented.

Comment: You dropped the numeral `1` from your question. `##1` is what you have to do when you `\(re)newcommand` with arguments within the definition of a `\newcommand`; this is so that the "inner" argument list can be distinguished from the "outer" argument list (which already uses `#1`). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42463/119

Comment: Note this doesn't have anything specifically to do with `etoolbox`. The doubling of hashes is a general thing in TeX.

Comment: `##` is standard tex processing and `!` is a local definition made in the post that you cite, a line above the code you show here.

Comment: The ! in the definition is an arbitrarily chosen delimiter for the loop. See [Parse macro arguments char by char and for loop through these chars](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/307581) for a simple example. In that code `\nil` is used as the delimiter. In the code in your question `!` is used just like `\nil` and in fact you can replace the `!` with `\nil` in the corrected code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587183/) to see that the choice is arbitrary.