# Generate tabular data dynamically including `\hline`

Tags: tables, foreach, hline

My question is same as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367979/234978) but with this different that I need an `\hline` after every row in `\tabledata`. How can I do it?

Currently my code is as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myTable}[1]{%
    \def\tabledata{}% reset \tabledata
    \foreach \lhs/\rhs in {#1} {% build table data from #1  
        \protected@xappto\tabledata{\textbf{\lhs} & \rhs \\}
    }%
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.35\textwidth}|p{0.65\textwidth}}
        \hline
        Headline 1 & Headline 2 \\ \hline
        \tabledata \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
   \myTable{{Title 1}/{Description 1}, {Title 2}/{Description 2}}
\end{document}
```

If I add `\hline` simply:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myTable}[1]{%
    \def\tabledata{}% reset \tabledata
    \foreach \lhs/\rhs in {#1} {% build table data from #1  
        \protected@xappto\tabledata{\textbf{\lhs} & \rhs \\ \hline}
    }%
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.35\textwidth}|p{0.65\textwidth}}
        \hline
        Headline 1 & Headline 2 \\ \hline
        \tabledata \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
   \myTable{{Title 1}/{Description 1}, {Title 2}/{Description 2}}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
Missing control sequence inserted.
```

Log File:

```
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.19 ...Description 1}, {Title 2}/{Description 2}}
                                                  
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.
```

And also it produces following result:
[image]

Comment: Because `hline` is still [fragile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands-when-and-why-do-we-n?noredirect=1&lq=1)...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\noexpand` before `\hline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myTable}[1]{%
    \def\tabledata{}% reset \tabledata
    \foreach \lhs/\rhs in {#1} {% build table data from #1  
        \protected@xappto\tabledata{\textbf{\lhs} & \rhs \\\noexpand\hline}
    }%
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.35\textwidth}|p{0.65\textwidth}}
        \hline
        Headline 1 & Headline 2 \\ \hline
        \tabledata %\hline %don't need
    \end{tabular}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
   \myTable{{Title 1}/{Description 1}, {Title 2}/{Description 2},{Title 3}/{Description 3}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a LaTeX3 version without `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \my_print_row:n #1 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {(.+)/(.+)} {\c{textbf}{\1} & \2} \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl \\ \hline
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\myTable} { >{\SplitList{,}}m } {
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.35\textwidth}|p{0.65\textwidth}}
        \hline
        Headline 1 & Headline 2 \\ \hline
        \ProcessList{#1}{\my_print_row:n}
    \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \myTable{Title 1/Description 1,Title 2/Description 2,Title 3/Description 3}
\end{document}
```

[image]